# How to make one bot work on different servers and have different prefixes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How to make one bot on different servers have a different prefix?

We can't use `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')`

One person said to use JSON, but I don’t understand how to configure the work of prefix from different servers in one `.py` file

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with creating a method takes parameters `bot`, `message`.

First, create a json file (or database) to store prefixes with guild ids.

Json file can be like this.

{
"123456789123456789": "!"
}

And now the code.

```
import json

def get_prefix(bot, message):
  with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
  return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #returning prefix that registered with guild's id
```

Last, registering the `Bot` object's `command_prefix` parameter.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

Comment: So, as a result, we will have some kind of prefix, but then the old prefix on another server will not work for us.